# How can i send data from two device in one code

Tags: c, serial-port

Process is
Ultrasonic sensor send distance data to PC => If Header is 0xff received packet is right

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    int ultrasonic = open("/dev/ttyUSB1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

    if (fd < 0 || ultrasonic < 0) {
    //Failed to open the serial port, exit
    return -1;
    } 

    struct termios oldtio = { 0 };
    struct termios newtio = { 0 };
    tcgetattr(fd, &oldtio);
    
    newtio.c_cflag = B9600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD | CRTSCTS;  //~CSTOPB CRTSCTS
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL; //IGNPAR | ICRNL
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;
    newtio.c_lflag = 0; // ICANON
    newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &newtio);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    tcgetattr(ultrasonic, &oldtio);
    tcflush(ultrasonic, TCIOFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(ultrasonic, TCSANOW, &newtio);
    fcntl(ultrasonic, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    unsigned char packet_ultrasonic[4]={};

    int ret = read(ultrasonic,packet_ultrasonic,sizeof(packet_ultrasonic));
    printf("ret : %d   %02x\n",ret,packet_ultrasonic[0]);
```

Follow the wiki of ultrasonic sensor, 'Header'(packet_ultrasonic[0]) must be 0xff but it is 0x5f.
'ret' is 4

chmod of all devices are 777. I already made ultrasonic sensor code and it works(I only use one serial port). I expected 'ret' is 4 and 'packet_ultrasonic[0]' is 0xff

Comment: The code reads the attributes into `oldtio` twice but never uses it. Is that intentional or did you mix up the variables?

Comment: Your use of termios is bad coding practice, See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Modes.html). You're using non-blocking mode, and turning an event-driven syscall into an inefficient poll. Why does your example code bother to open & setup two serial terminals, when you only use one terminal? "*chmod of all devices are 777*" -- Another bad practice; you need to learn how to assign users to a group. "*If Header is 0xff received packet is right*" -- That's a really weak packet validation that doesn't suffice in the real world.